# Stream a set of Strings into Map of <String, ArrayList()>

Tags: java, set, java-stream

I have a set of Strings (it's static) and I would like to create a `Map<String, List<String>>` from them, where the list is initialized to a new ArrayList. Something like the following, but this code is not correct.

```
static Set<String> MY_TYPES = Set.of("type1", "type2", "type3");

Map<String, List<String> myMap = MY_TYPES.stream().map(t->() t, new ArrayList<>()).collect(Collectors.toMap());
```

I am trying to learn how to use streams better in my code. I know I can do this iterating over the Set.

### Edit

@shmosel, you are correct. I want the equivalent of

```
Map.of("type1", new ArrayList<>(), "type2", new ArrayList<>(), "type3", new ArrayList());
```

Comment: What do you expect `Map<String, List<String>>` to contain (based on your example)?

Comment: Could you elaborate what is a key and what is a value in map elements?

Comment: I think he wants empty lists.

Comment: You want an empty list for each item? Just `collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s -> new ArrayList<>())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for this:

```
MY_TYPES.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> new ArrayList<>()))
```